# How to decrease the volume of sound using pyaudio?

Tags: python, audio

I am using `pyaudio` to hear some sound that is in a `numpy` array `samples` (`python` 3.9.6). Using the following code:

```
volume = 0.0002
output_bytes = (volume * samples).tobytes()

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively)
start_time = time.time()
stream.write(output_bytes)
print("Played sound for {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time))

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

the sound should be extremely silent (as the `volume` variable is 0.0002), but in fact the sound plays extremely loud. Setting the `volume` variable to some other value does not seem to have any effect.

How can I make the sound play more silent? Or can I use another library for that? Also, I am using a Mac; maybe it is a MacOS issue...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried normalizing the audio samples? This could potentially fix the issue as it would bring all of the audio samples into the range of -1.0 to 1.0.

samples = samples / np.max(np.abs(samples))

If that doesn't work, maybe try using sounddevice to manage the sound output:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np

# Generate a 1 second sine wave at 440 Hz
fs = 44100
duration = 1.0
freq = 440.0
t = np.linspace(0, duration, int(fs * duration), False)
samples = 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t)

# Play the audio
sd.play(samples, fs)
sd.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to post a deleted answer which is the correct answer by user
"user21587607". It seems I did not use `float` values which generated
the problem. Kudos go to user "user21587607":

> It looks like you're having trouble adjusting the sound volume using
> PyAudio. One possible reason is that your samples array may not be in
> a float format, so make sure to convert it to float before scaling it
> with the volume variable.
>
> Here's a modified version of your code:
>
> ```
> # Convert samples to float32
> samples = samples.astype(np.float32)
>
> # Scale the samples with the volume
> scaled_samples = volume * samples
>
> # Clip the values to make sure they're in the valid range for paFloat32
> clipped_samples = np.clip(scaled_samples, -1.0, 1.0)
>
> # Convert the array to bytes and play the sound
> output_bytes = clipped_samples.tobytes()
>
> stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
>                 channels=1,
>                 rate=fs,
>                 output=True)
>
> start_time = time.time()
> stream.write(output_bytes)
> print("Played sound for {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time))
>
> stream.stop_stream()
> stream.close()
>
> p.terminate()
> ```
>
> Now you should be able to control the volume by tweaking the volume
> variable. If it's still too loud, just lower the value even more. Hope
> this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.